# the value or constructor 'handShakeWithSubprotocol' is not defined in websocket example

Tags: .net-core, suave

I am using .NET Core 2.0. I created an F# console app. In Program.fs I put the [Suave WebSocket example code.](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/tree/master/examples/WebSocket)

Everything compiles except for line 84:

```
path "/websocketWithSubprotocol" >=> handShakeWithSubprotocol (chooseSubprotocol "test") ws
```

I get this error

```
error FS0039: The value or constructor 'handShakeWithSubprotocol' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:↔   handShakeResponse↔   handShake
```

I searched the Suave source code and I found [`handShakeWithSubprotocol` in WebSocket.fs](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/76a15f6f922c8f6f20a2713aff43ee6fd8d1502c/src/Suave/WebSocket.fs). So I think this should be accessible, but the compiler doesn't think so.

What could be going wrong?

You can see all of my code [here](https://github.com/mandelbrotmesh/websocket-server).

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured this out.

`handShakeWithSubprotocol` is not in v 2.2.1 which is the version of Suave I am using. [Looks like it was added 4 months ago according to blame.](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blame/master/src/Suave/WebSocket.fs)

[Link to the source code tagged v2.2.1](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/v2.2.1/src/Suave/WebSocket.fs)

[Looks like it's not in 2.3.0-beta either.](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/v2.3.0-beta/src/Suave/WebSocket.fs), but there is a pull request saying it might make it into 2.3.0.